# How can I handle requests to routes that don't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm sure information on this already exists, but I searched and don't know if my search terms are correct.

I have a node/express application and I want it so that when a user requests a route that doesn't exist, the server will return a specific page rather than the default "Cannot get X" page.

for example, if someone reqeusts

```
application/asdf
```

but no route exists, I'd like to render the 404 page.

How does one do this?

Comment: Found this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528876/how-to-redirect-404-errors-to-a-page-in-expressjs. Helpful?

Comment: Found the answer in the 2nd comment, thank you!

Comment: @Eogcloud They both work, but I'd suggest using the method in the first method rather than the second.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found my answer! Thank you @dollarVar

2nd answer: [How to redirect 404 errors to a page in ExpressJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528876/how-to-redirect-404-errors-to-a-page-in-expressjs)

> I think you should first define all your routes and as the last route
>   add
>
> ```
> //The 404 Route (ALWAYS Keep this as the last route)
> app.get('*', function(req, res){
>   res.send('what???', 404);
> });
> ```