# Default route in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

I'm writing an application with node.js and express.

I have setup a default route as this :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('./views/index.html');
});
```

This works fine when I goto /localhost:port/

But in the URL when I type anything after that,  /localhost:port/blah  I get 404 ERROR which makes sense.

I want to setup a default route so that no matter what I type in the URL after localhost:port/  it should all get back the same html file.

I tried changing / to * :

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('./views/index.html');
});
```

but after I do this  I start getting this error in the console and nothing shows up:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

in all of my Javascript files: :3000/scripts/myscript.js:1

somehow my javascript file show the content of HTML

===EDIT====

I used this and it worked fine for first level urls: like loclhost:port/blah

```
app.use(function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('./views/index.html');
});
```

but when the URLs are multilevel, I see the same problem as described earlier localhost:port/blah/foo
The problem here is that router is looking for public directory under /blah folder for all the javascript and CSS files in this case, which does not exist. And it's returning the default HTML file. How do I fix this?

==================EDIT POSTING THE WHOLE CODE =========================================

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var api = require('./routes/api');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/api/user/:userid', api.getUserInfo);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('./views/index.html');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

In addition to this, I have an HTML with a myscript linked in it,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/myscript.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code?

Comment: Your site is loading your JS files and these request are probably served by your "catch-all" .get '*'. Browser expects JavaScript file but gets your index.html. This indicates you don't really want ALL your URLs to be served with index.html.

Comment: Hmm. You would think that because it comes first, the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` line should take precedence. :/

Comment: so how do I avoid that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As stated [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/express-js/aYLM4e1I4XU/jr7YloDfsbkJ), you can add this middleware just after your routing logic:

```
   app.use(function(req, res){
       res.send(404);
   });
```

You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9802006) also useful.

Of course, you need to adapt the `res.send()` part to meet your needs.

Comment: I added this   app.use(function(req, res){ res.sendfile('./views/index.html');  });  and it worked for url/anything , but there is still a problem, when I type two levels in my url like localhost:port/anything/anything it throws up the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: ok the problem is when I say localhost:port/blah/anything, All the GET requests for javascript files are under /blah directory which does not exist, and so it is returning the HTML file.

Answer (score 33):

Add this route at the **after of all your previous routes**

```
app.get('*',function (req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

This will redirect any route not handled to the index "/"

Comment: This does work, but for some reason `request.url` always contains "/" instead of a full path which was specified.

Answer (score 4):

With the newer version of express I would suggest using res.sendStatus as res.send has been deprecated.

Express v3

```
app.use(function(req, res){
   res.send(404);
});
```

Express v4

```
app.use(function(req, res){
   res.sendStatus(404);
});
```

Comment: In Express 4.x you can also use `res.status(404).send('Sorry, we cannot find that!')`  if you don't  want to use the predefined status message for the status code ( `Not Found` in this case)