# express js - Form data does not submit?

Tags: express, form-data

I am working with form data in express js and i use route solution based on [guide of Mukesh Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749288/separate-file-for-routes-in-express/41423268#41423268).

app.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

auth.js

```
module.exports = {
    login : function(req, res, next){
       res.render('admin/login', { baseUrl: baseUrl, title: 'Auth Site' });
    },
    loginSubmit : function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('here');
        console.log(req.body);
    }
}
```

route.js

```
var adminAuthController = require(__dirname + '/controllers/admin/auth');
router.route('/admin/login').get(adminAuthController.login);
router.route('/admin/login').post(adminAuthController.loginSubmit);
```

login.pug

```
form(action="/admin/login", method="POST")
        div
            label(for="username") Username: 
            input(name="username" value="")
        br
        div
            label(for="password") Password: 
            input(name="password" type="password" value="")
        br
        button(type="submit") Send my greetings
```

Now, login page is showed ok. But after submit, loginSubmit function does not working. It consoled "here" text but req.body is undefined ? 
Can you explain for me ?
Many thanks !

Comment: make sure app.use('/api', routes); in your app.js is after  app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: oh, thank shivshankar ! It works very well!