# Express js :separate controller and router file returns 404 error on route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like seprate all of my routes from the `app.js` file into a seprat
 `route` file which will loads the controllers from the controller directory.

Here is my folder structure

```
<project folder>
   controllers
         testController.js
   routes
        route.js
app.js
```

Here is my `testController.js`

```
module.exports = {
    getMovie : function(req, res){
        //do something
        res.send('respond with test resource');
    },
    postMovie : function(req, res){
        //do something
    }
}
```

`route.js` under `route` directory.

```
var express = require('express');
//load the contrller
var test = require('../controllers/testController.js');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/hello').get(test.getMovie);

module.exports = router;
```

when i access my route `localhost:3000/hello` i got 404 error.

I just tried the solutions from this question  [separate file for routes in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749288/separate-file-for-routes-in-express)

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes');

var app = express();
app.use('api',routes);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Update

```
var routes = require('./route')
```

to

```
var routes = require('./routes/route');
```

Comment: `Have you included it in app.js?how to include??
`

Comment: Link you referes also mentioned  it 
var routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/api', routes);

Comment: Yes its included

Comment: can you please also add app.js above

Comment: app.use('api',routes); means /api is prefix so your url should be localhost:3000/api/hello

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139453/discussion-between-ritesh-arora-and-jabaa).

Comment: Yeah just applied it but again i got 404:)