# How to catch 404 error in Express/Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

I confused when catch 404 error and when not?
I want achieve the goal when input correct request path will not catch 404 error,otherwise bad request path will.

Comment: [Related post for catching 404s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528876/how-to-redirect-404-errors-to-a-page-in-expressjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes folder(if you are using express-gen) or anywhere else create a node module which uses `express.router()` as follows

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var dishRouter = express.Router();

dishRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Then handle your requests, example:

```
dishRouter.route('/')
.get(function(req, res, next) {
    res.end('Will send all the dishes to you!');
})

.post(function(req, res, next) {
    res.end('Will add the dish: ' + req.body.name + ' with details: ' + req.body.description);
});
```

And use this in ur app.js or the main file which you run:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var dishRouter=require('./routes/dishRouter');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/dishes',dishRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  res.redirect('/fail');
  next(err);
});
```

So what this will do is that, it will handle the get and post requests from client for URI `/dishes` and for others, it will throw an error 404 and send to `/fail` path.

Comment: see your example and i find it seems to understand it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the express use() is executed for **all** request, so what is happening is your 404 status is attached to all request within your application. Use it in the callback which checks whether the input is correct or not, for example if its an HTTP express post request:

```
// This is just an example, please note
app.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
    if(!user.passwordCheck(req.body.password) {
        res.status(404).send({
            message: 'Incorrect input'
        }); 
    } else res.redirect('/success');
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your good explanation and it will help me deeply understand about this question.

Comment: @ivanJF how about a tick if it helped, lol. Glad to help