# Vue js deploying in production seems harder then it is

Tags: nginx, vue.js, deployment, vue-cli-3

I've created simple Vue JS App using **Vue-cli 3**. I have a digitalocean droplet with Nginx + php.
My goal is to host Vue App on the same droplet.
I have already tried:

- Add certain `location /` to nginx conf.
- Used this simple node server: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

And what I get i s`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`:
[image: console output]

Interesting thing, when I use `npm run build` to make production resources into `dist` directory and use `php -S localhost:8080` it is hosted like a charm. But the same thing with simple node js server causes the result on the screenshot above.

I've been struggling for 2 days straight. Halp me please.

Comment: sounds like it may be a syntax error in your nginx configuration file. Post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue. The problem was that when the browser requests the javascript and css files, the contents of the index file is sent instead.

Solved it by following step 3 of this [tutorial](https://medium.com/netscape/deploying-a-vue-js-2-x-app-to-heroku-in-5-steps-tutorial-a69845ace489).

> Since Vue is only a frontend library, the easiest way to host it and
>   do things like serve up assets is to create a simple Express friendly
>   script that Heroku can use to start a mini-web server. Read up quickly
>   on Express if you haven’t already. After that, add express:

```
npm install express --save
```

> Now add a server.js file to your project’s root directory:

```
// server.js

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('server started '+ port);
```

After that, since the idea is to serve index.html in the first place, I borrowed this [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9802006/7378516) and added the following to my code (notice I used sendFile if the request is html):

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404)

    if (req.accepts("html")) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/dist/index.html"))
        return
    }

    if (req.accepts("json")) {
        res.send({error: "Not found"})
        return
    }

    res.type("txt").send("Not found")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but I have used this to `sendFile index.html` up on 404 response.

```js
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
console.error(err.stack);
res.status(404).sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "dist", "index.html"));
})
```

Explanation:
err will be defined when the request is erroneous. res.status will set the status to 404 code and the app will `sendFile` the resolved index.html. (Notice that I used __dirname and path.resolve together to build an absolute path to be safe.