# How can i handle Angular 404 request in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6, angular5

I am using angular 6 and Server sided rendering with nodejs. i have a question how can i handle 404 route with nodejs instead of angular

what i  want is 404 headers + no JavaScript etc i simply want a plain html code with 404 page not found written under a H1 tag  nothing else like angular JavaScripts etc but i am not able to do it please help me

below are my routing with angular

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
   { path: 'somepage', component: SomePageComponent },
   { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent}
];
```

My Nodejs SSR Implementation

```
module.exports = function (app, js) {
    require('zone.js/dist/zone-node');
    require('reflect-metadata');
    const express = require('express');
    const { enableProdMode } = require('@angular/core');
    const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require(js.root.dist + 'server/main.bundle');
    const { ngExpressEngine } = require('@nguniversal/express-engine');
    const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');
enableProdMode();
    app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
        bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
        providers: [
            provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
        ]
    }));

    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views', js.root.dist+'browser');
    app.get('*.*', express.static(js.root.dist+'browser',{
  maxage: '2h'
}));
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.render('index', { req }, (err, html) => {
            res.send(html);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528876/how-to-redirect-404-errors-to-a-page-in-expressjs

Comment: i have checked it before posting my question actually i want redirect from server side  instead of redirecting from client side

Comment: from ErrorComponent's ts file you can call 404 api of nodejs

Comment: still in frontend it will load angularjs javascript i want a simple 404 page with 404 headers and simlple html code