# Express: Avoid undefined/unused routes

Tags: node.js, api, express

I'm building a small microservice with express, and I'd like to know how to avoid undefined routes,
i.e:

In my API, I'v defined just and endpoint,

```
/api/myendpoint
```

Which works as expected, but if I send any kind of reques to the same host+server where express is running, i.e

```
/api/route/dont/exist
```

I get a ugly html response, which I would like to avoid, or return some kind of custom message

I been digging a bit but I coulnt find any solution

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528876/how-to-redirect-404-errors-to-a-page-in-expressjs

Answer (score 2):

[Custom error handling](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) in Express.

In a nutshell, it looks like this:

```
// custom error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
});
```

You put this after your other middleware.  See the documentation link above for more info.  This lets you control what response is sent back to the client if a route handler is not found for the specific incoming request or if any route calls `next(err)` with an error.  This middleware handler will only get called in those cases of an error.  You can then send any response you want.