# 404 pages using javascript node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, function, http-status-code-404

I am learning how to redirect a user to a 404 page when an ending doesn't lead to any page. I am stuck on how to redirect the user to the page. I am not sure if I got the URL ending part input wrong or if I got the send file part wrong.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
    app.get('/:type', (req, res)=> {
    let path = require('path');
    res.status(404).sendFile('404.html');
    });
```

Comment: Are you using express.js?

Comment: @kevintechie yes, I have looked at the website and still a bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to handle 404, you might need to add this route at the end of app.js:

```
//The 404 Route (ALWAYS Keep this as the last route)
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send('Not Found');
});
```

Or,

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new httpError(404)
  return next(err);
});
```

If you are using `express`, it will be handled by it. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528876/how-to-redirect-404-errors-to-a-page-in-expressjs) link and it has many options almost similar to each other if the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using express.js. The [Express FAQ](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html) answers this question. Look under "How do I handle 404 responses?"

In your case, something like this should work:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).sendFile('./pathTo/404.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just forgot to use the path.join function after importing it ;)

Don't forget to join the dirname( __dirname) with your filename.

```
const path = require('path');
app.get('*', (req, res)=> {
    res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/404.html"));
});
```

use it after all your routes not before them.

if you want to send this file just in case of a get request then this should do it but if you want it for all requests then you should use app.use in place of app.get

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused between front-end routing and back-end routing, please refer [this](https://medium.com/@kennedyjt88/frontend-routing-vs-backend-routing-874b2bc41e5a#:~:text=In%20backend%20routing%2C%20the%20server,don%27t%20have%20that!).&text=Frontend%20routing%20is%20handled%20from,GET%20request%20to%20the%20server.) . They are handled separately, and you are kind of mixing them together.

From what I understood, that you are trying to redirect the user to a 404 custom html error page you can do that like this but in front-end side (ANGULAR).

`{path:"**",pathMatch:"full",redirectTo:"/home"}`

Also its better to redirect them to "home" page instead of error page for better user experience. 404 custom-error page could be used for different purposes such as network failure, server down ,code break-down(Note: they are also for better user experience.)

In node.js its an endpoint and these APIs are called internally by developers, you get a request either you have the response or you don't, in case you don't you can do something like this

```js
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send('Not Found');
});
```

If you found this answer useful please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)